# Retrieve value of 5th to 10th titles in a collection of 15-16 titles using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Below is my XML file and I would like to retrieve titles 3 to 4 of the XML file using some form of count function with XSLT. Please help... thanks for your help

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<result>
 <cd><xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd[3]/title"/></cd>
 <cd><xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd[4]/title"/></cd>
</result>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for a range of title (see question/title). Here you are too specific.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position) XPath function.

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
      <xsl:copy-of 
        select="catalog/cd[position() &gt;= 3 and position() &lt;= 4]/title"/>
    </result>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This short and completely "push style" transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="cd/node()"/>
 <xsl:template match="cd[position() >= 3 and 4 >= position()]/title">
     <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<title>Greatest Hits</title>
<title>Still got the blues</title>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The empty-bodied template `<xsl:template match="cd/node()"/>` prevents the processing ("deletes") of any child of a `cd` .
2. The second template overrides the first only for a `title` child of a `cd` whose `position()` is not less than 3 and not greater than 4. It effectively copies the matched `title` element.
3. The `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` instruction makes all this possible by deleting from the XML document all white-space-only text nodes. In this way the positions of `cd` elements in the node-list formed by the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction (in the built-in XSLT template for elements) would be 1, 2, 3, 4 and not 2, 4, 6, 8.